# When I open my http://localhost:9999/ the page is not found; what is the problem?

Tags: google-app-engine

Im using google app engine python with aptana studio 3 and pydev;

The debug config is:

```
mainmodule: C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\dev_appserver.py
```

arguments:

```
"${project_loc:test}/src"
--port=9999
```

and the console is:

```
pydev debugger: warning: psyco not available for speedups (the debugger will still work correctly, but a bit slower)
pydev debugger: starting
WARNING  2011-02-24 11:11:09,447 urlfetch_stub.py:74] No ssl package found. urlfetch will not be able to validate SSL certificates.
INFO     2011-02-24 11:11:09,665 appengine_rpc.py:153] Server: appengine.google.com
WARNING  2011-02-24 11:11:09,691 datastore_file_stub.py:573] Could not read datastore data from C:\Users\Psoares\Desktop\outros\WEB DEV\Rubete 2010 Survey\ds
WARNING  2011-02-24 11:11:09,703 dev_appserver.py:3700] Could not initialize images API; you are likely missing the Python "PIL" module. ImportError: No module named _imaging
INFO     2011-02-24 11:11:09,726 dev_appserver_main.py:507] Running application rubete2010survey on port 9999: http://localhost:9999
```

when i go to http://localhost:9999; the page is not found;

the app.yaml is:

```
application: rubete2010survey
version: 1
runtime: python
api_version: 1

handlers:  
    - url: /.*
      script: main.py
```

the main.py is:

```
print 'Content-Type: text/plain'
print ''
print 'Hello, world!'
```

they are in the same folder; test/src

what's the problem?

Comment: After you send the request in the browser, is any additional information printed out in the development server console? Generally, if there is a problem, useful information will be printed there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try with:
http://127.0.0.1:9999

in case it works, add `localhost` to your `hosts` file.

Answer (score 0):

```
pip install pil
pip install ssl
```